# Selectively connect to bluetooth services on specific peripheral

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My (indoor cycling) Smart Trainer & Crank Power Meter (individually) advertises a few services

Indoor Trainer:

```
Primary - Service        - Cycling Power Service (1818)
        - Characteristic - Cycling Power

Primary - Service        - Fitness Control (FTMS)
        - Characteristic - Cycling Power
                         - Trainer Target Power (from user)
```

Crank Power Meter:

```
 Primary - Service        - Cycling Power Service (1818)
         - Characteristic - Cycling Power
```

with the cycling power service (1818), it advertises transmitted power data but there's no way to control the trainer resistance.

with FTMS, it advertises transmitted power and has a way to send targeted power to it (trainer resistance control)

When CoreBluetooth connects to my indoor trainer device, it (my current code) will automatically list both services and connects to it. (This is not what I want)

I can of course remove the Cycling Power (1818) service when I connect to the indoor trainer but this is not desired as that would remove any ability to connect to other peripherals which offers only the cycling power service

```
var services = [serviceHeartRateCBUUID,
                serviceCyclingSpeedAndCadenceUUID,
                serviceCyclingPowerUUID, 
                serviceFTMSUUID]

centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: services)
```

After scanning, I then connect to the peripherals & discover the services it offers using (passing the list of services I'm interested in which again includes both the FTMS and Cycling Power Service) With this, I end up w/ 2 connections to the indoor trainer (instead of 1 which I desire)

```
 peripheral.discoverServices(services)
```

**The Ask:**
The solution I'm searching for is to be able to **only** connect to the FTMS service on the Indoor trainer while also be able to connect to the crank power meter.

The workaround I'm thinking of is basically to enable a switch for the user to select between FTMS vs Cycling Power Meter, thereby if the user has Both an indoor trainer & a crank power meter connected simultaneously.

Searching stackoverflow and goggle didn't yield me anything useful, all of them just shows how to connect to services (by listing the in the "services" variable like example above)

Update 1:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
    
    for service in services {
      print("  >> Discover Services Found : \(service.uuid) service")
      peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
    }
  }
```

In didDiscoverServices func, Looping thru the services found these 2

```
>> Discover Services Found : 1818 service
>> Discover Services Found : FTMS service
```

after which it calls `peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)`

How can I use the info from `didDiscoverServices` (once it detects both FTMS and 1818) to actually ignore 1818?

Comment: Are the Indoor Trainer and Crank Power Meter two separate Bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion w/ @SJoshi, I managed to achieve my goal. Only thing is that the code seems overly complicated with 3 different loops needed to achieve the goal.

```
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

    var discoveredServices = [CBUUID]()
    var btServicesOffered = [CBService?]()
    
    guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
    print("\nThere are \(services.count) service(S) advertised namely:")
    
    for service in services {
      print("  >> \(service.uuid) service")

      // Results in discoveredServices:[1818, FTMS]
      discoveredServices.append(CBUUID(string: service.uuid.uuidString))
      btServicesOffered.append(service)
    }
  
    // Can actually remove btServicesOffered as not really used
    print("  >>>>> btServicesOffered:\(btServicesOffered)")
    
    if discoveredServices.contains(FTMS) && discoveredServices.contains(1818) {
      print("\n  >> This is a Smart Trainer advertising 2 services. Connect ONLY to FTMS")

      for service in services {
        if service.uuid == FTMS {
          print("  >> Connecting to FTMS")
          peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        } else if service.uuid == 1818 {
          print("  >> Doing NOTHING for 1818")
        }
      }
    } else {
      for service in services {
        print("  >> Discover Services Found : \(service.uuid) service")
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
      }
    }
    print()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the power meter, and indoor trainer are two separate Bluetooth devices, then there shouldn't be any issue.

The way BLE works, is that a central connects to a peripheral, then you can discover services on that peripheral, and use/not use whatever you'd like.

So, you can continue to scan for all the peripherals you'd like (regardless of what they advertise), then connect, discover services/characteristics - and just make use of whatever combination/permutation you'd like.

If you're interested in saving a bit of power, and maybe cleaning up code, upon connection to a peripheral, you can selectively discoverServices (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518706-discoverservices) - and you can essentially handle your service filtering that way.

Comment: Yes. 2 separate devices (edited my post). Currently, when I connect to each of the device, I pass them the list of services I would like to connect to. In this case, I like to connect to BOTH the cycling power & FTMS service.  Once I scanned / connect the the peripheral, I then call ```peripheral.discoverServices(services)``` for each device. and thus this leads me to this current situation where it will connect to both cycling power & FTMS on the indoor trainer. I do not know how I can filter the services based on the peripheral I'm connected to.

Comment: Is there a way to know I'm connected/connecting to a Smart Trainer vs a Crank Power Meter for example? AFAIK, it doesn't advertise itself as "I'm a smart trainer - and I offer both cycling power and FTMS services" vs "I'm a Crank Power Meter - and I offer cycling power meter only"

Comment: Aha, the crux of the problem - you don't know which device you're connecting to? So, there are a slew of ways to do it, but it's dependent on your workflow. You could a) scan twice (once for a certain subset of services, then again for the full set of services), b) look for certain advertisement data that differs between each, c) read the "device info" Bluetooth Gatt - which usually specifies a manufacturer, a device name, etc, d) connect to all of them, and see which ones fail to discover certain services, etc etc etc

Comment: I should also mention, I don't think you actually have 2 connections to one peripheral from one iPhone... While it may technically be possible, I don't know if it's possible at the Bluetooth layer. More likely, you're retaining two instances in code for the same underlying peripheral (e.g. by peripheral UID)

Comment: Yes. Users can have a Indoor trainer, a crank power meter, a hub power meter, a pedal power meter and all of them can offer some variation of features/services/characteristics and my code will juggle it. My current thinking is to offer the user a switch to choose between Crank Power vs Indoor Trainer but this comes also w/ caveat that it can _still_ connect to the Indoor Trainer's Cycling Power Service. *headache* [I guess this is why some trainer app I use _will_ not connect to FTMS but only Cycling Power, which is useless since can't control my trainer's resistance automatically)

Comment: you are right, it's 1 connection to the Indoor Trainer, but it's subscribing to _both_ the Cycling Power Service & the FTMS service and thus I'm getting Power Data from _both_ these services in the code (under the same indoor Trainer UUID)

Comment: So, that last point is the confusing one - you decide what to subscribe to for notifications, so if you have a device with an FTMS service - then wouldn't you just not subscribe to Cycling Power Service notifications from that one? Or rather, from that one's characteristic? By definition, it sounds like you have enough information to infer what the device probably is, so you can action each one independently. I do something similar in a project, and each connection subscribes to different characteristics, depending on which specific device I infer it to be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224557/discussion-between-myjunk-and-sjoshi).